# How to use linear algebra to solve this question?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find a unit vector that is orthogonal to both i+j and i+k.

I know how to do it with calculus but I was wondering how I could solve this using matrix.

Comment: Have you tried taking the cross product?

Comment: I’m curious. How would you use calculus to solve this? Seems like the wrong set of tools to me.

Comment: What are i, j, k? Are you working with quaternions? In that case, shouldn't it be unit quaternion?

Comment: I know, I learned linear alegbra and I am confused as to why I have to answer with calculus.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let the vector you're trying to find be $\ x\mathbf{i} + y\mathbf{j} + z\mathbf{k}\ $. For this to be orthogonal to $\ \mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j}\ $ and $\ \mathbf{i} + \mathbf{k}\ $, you require
\begin{align}
0&=(x\mathbf{i} + y\mathbf{j} + z\mathbf{k})\cdot(\mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j})=x+y\ ,\ \text{and}\\
0&=(x\mathbf{i} + y\mathbf{j} + z\mathbf{k})\cdot(\mathbf{i} + \mathbf{k})=x+z\ .
\end{align}
To write down the general solution of these equations it's not necessary to convert them to matrix form, but do you know how to do so if you want?

Answer (score 0):

i+j=(1,1,0)
i+k=(1,0,1)
Take cross product (1,1,0)*(1,0,1)=1i-1j-1k=(1,-1,-1)

I'm curious that how can you solve this by Calculus.